# Subclass UIview to create selector

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, subclass

I am trying to subclass UIView to create a selection box where a user can choose a range of filters (that I will ultimately apply to a UITableView). I have created a custom class like this

```
import UIKit

class FilterView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.addFilterView()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    var lblFilter = UILabel()
    var butApply = UIButton()

    func addFilterView() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        frame = Layout.filterFrame
        self.butApply.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 60, width: 60, height: 30)
        self.butApply.setTitle("Apply", for: .normal)
        self.addSubview(butApply)
    }
}
```

(Layout.filterFrame is a struct that returns a CGRect)

And then use this subclass within a View Controller to try and get the window to pop up

```
let f = FilterView(frame: Layout.filterFrame)

@IBAction func butFilter(_ sender: Any) {
    //f.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    //f.frame = Layout.filterFrame
    self.view.addSubview(f)
```

All that happens is that I get a completely white screen with nothing on it. However, if I uncomment the lines in the @IBAction to set background colour and frame, then the pop-up window works fine. Is it not possible to set frame and background etc within the subclass directly so that I don't have to set it every time I use it? Isn't the point of a sub-class to define these things once so they can be used as-is anywhere?

Comment: I have copy paste your class replace  Layout.filterFrame to `CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 450, height: 450)` and add subview to viewDidLoad and it is showing popup view.

Comment: make sure your subview is in front. or try to bringSubViewToFront

Comment: I have just found what I was doing wrong - I am an idiot - there was some test code further down that was, in fact setting the frame to full screen, white. Remove this and everything works fine. Sorry to waste your time. Learning point for me!